# how to render the web browser and get x y coordinates of html tags(e.f. "<img", "<div", so on...) and take a screen shot them in C#?

Tags: c#, html, css, svg

I'd like to get some screenshots(as an image) that is one of many HTML elements by using C#. I just need to know about making each step.

1. Load Internet Explorer and web URL(e.g. stackoverflow.com, so
   on...).
2. Parse the DOM(Document Object Model) structure.
3. Render this web page.
4. Get the x y coordinates(or
   position information) of HTML elements that I want to get(e.f.
   "<img", "<div", so on...). In this section, it does not matter
   which HTML element it is.
5. Take screenshots by using the x y
   coordinates and width, height, ....

but until now, I haven't finished this project because I don't know how to, in fact, I'm not even sure these steps are correct.

So, please tell me how can I can finish this project and if these steps are correct, please revise my information also, if you know a more efficient or correct code.

p.s. I made this code by referencing other codes until now.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string webPageURL = "http://www.google.com";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webPageURL);
            request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            //IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("SubmitButton"));
            //Point point = element.Location;
            //Console.WriteLine("X cordinate : " + point.X + "Y cordinate: " + point.Y);

            SvgPoint sp = new SvgPoint();
            //SvgRenderer sr = new SvgRenderer();
            //SvgElement se = new SvgElement;
            SvgPointCollection spc = new SvgPointCollection();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string htmlContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    List<Uri> links = FetchLinksFromSource(htmlContent);

                    for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(links[i]);
                    }

                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
                        { 
                            WebBrowser WebBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
                            //WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img");

                            IHTMLElement htmldoc = (IHTMLElement)new HTMLDocument();
                            //IHTMLElement htmldoc1 = (IHTMLElement)Document.body;

                            WebBrowser1.Navigate(webPageURL);

                            sp.X = findPosX(htmldoc);
                            sp.Y = findPosY(htmldoc);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        public static List<Uri> FetchLinksFromSource(string htmlSource)
        {
            List<Uri> links = new List<Uri>();
            string regexImgSrc = @"<img[^>]*?src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]*?>";
            MatchCollection matchesImgSrc = Regex.Matches(htmlSource, regexImgSrc, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
            foreach (Match m in matchesImgSrc)
            {
                string href = m.Groups[1].Value;
                links.Add(new Uri(href));
            }
            return links;
        }


        public static int findPosX(IHTMLElement obj)
        {
            int curleft = 0;
            if (obj.offsetParent != null)
            {
                while (obj.offsetParent != null)
                {
                    curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
                    obj = obj.offsetParent;
                }
            }

            return curleft;
        }


        public static int findPosY(IHTMLElement obj)
        {
            int curtop = 0;
            if (obj.offsetParent != null)
            {
                while (obj.offsetParent != null)
                {
                    curtop += obj.offsetTop;
                    obj = obj.offsetParent;
                }
            }

            return curtop;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which of the steps are you stuck on? What exactly is wrong with your code? I.e. which step does it not do correctly?

Comment: Instead of use HttpWebRequest and render it by yourself, you can use selenium and take control of a browser, and get render and position easily